# Cannot Rasterize in QGIS from points?

Tags: qgis, rasterization

This is the error I get:

```
GDAL command output:
ERROR 4: `file:///C:/Users/User/OneDrive/Raredirt/Home%203%20Data/home%203%202011%20jademungplanting.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
Process returned error code 1
```

I'm trying to create a raster of the elevation from this .csv data.

[image]

and these are my input parameters.
[image]

Comment: Try saving your csv file as a geopackage or shapefile and run the Rasterize tool on that.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Had not read that anywhere. Still cannot get the pixel size right but I think I was actually wanting grid as explained below as that has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize if you know all this. Not sure what the purpose is from your question. If you just want to make an elevation map from some point data, try **gdal_grid**.

```
gdal_grid -l points.shp -zfield elevation -a invdistnn:power=2.0:smothing=0.0:radius=1.0:max_points=12:min_points=2:nodata=-99999.0 -ot Float32 -txe 144.5 146.5 -tye -69 -68 -outsize 100 100 -of GTiff poits_with_el.shp OUTPUT.tif
```

works for me.

If you are actually rasterizing, try doing it from the command line:

```
gdal_rasterize  -a elevation -a_srs EPSG:4326 -te 144.5 -69 146.5 -68 -ts 100 100 points.shp a.tif
```

Both of these methods work from a point layer. Rasterizing just makes some points on a blank grid. Gridding interpolates the data to the grid, which can be contoured.

[image: Points]

A set of points

[image: Rasterised Points]

Rasterised points

[image: Gridded Points]

Gridded points

[image: Gridded & Contoured Points]

Gridded & Contoured Points

Comment: Thanks, the gdal grid worked for me, maybe that is what i wanted all along rather the rasterise. I'm new as well so thanks for the help.

Comment: @skermo in QGIS, there are other methods as well, such as TIN and kriging, in the GRASS and SAGA addins. I can never get them to work on Mac, so I usually go to the command line, where you can change parameters and rerun quite easily.